# Is there any way to edit CSS/JS of WebComponent?

Tags: javascript, css, ionic4, web-component, native-web-component

I am a web developer and recently started working with Ionic 4 which is based on Web Component. I was trying to edit the CSS of the components but I was not able to edit the same and later on figured out that it was because of Web-Components which do have #shadow-root.

My Question is, Is there any way to edit the CSS and JS of a Web Component.
If not, why is it there?

The drawbacks of the same according to me are:
- Not able to apply the custom CSS into the child components of the Component.
- Plugins like Stylus will be useless as the CSS won't be applied and we won't be able to get the dark mode.

Answer (score 2):

The Component ***Author*** decides the level of styling that can be applied.

**When there is no `#shadow-root`**

- All global CSS applied
- all children are part of the main document DOM

**With ShadowDOM created with `this.attachShadow({mode:"open"})`**

- No global CSS applied
- Inheritable styles are applied (font, color, etc.)
- CSS Properties (if used by the Component author) are applied
- `part` definitions (set by author) can be styled with global CSS
- You can access the `shadowRoot` and overwrite everything inside
  *(its like buying an IKEA table and putting a saw in it)*

**shadowDOM created with `this.attachShadow({mode:"closed"})`**

- as above
- BUT  You can **not** access the `shadowRoot`

### Documentation

source: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom

> **TL;DR**
>
> Shadow DOM removes the brittleness of building web apps. The
> brittleness comes from the global nature of HTML, CSS, and JS. Over
> the years we've invented an exorbitant [number of tools](http://getbem.com/introduction/) to circumvent
> the issues. For example, when you use a new HTML id/class, there's no
> telling if it will conflict with an existing name used by the page.
> [Subtle bugs](http://www.2ality.com/2012/08/ids-are-global.html) creep up, CSS specificity becomes a huge issue (!important
> all the things!), style selectors grow out of control, and [performance
> can suffer](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/css-containment). The list goes on.
>
> **Shadow DOM fixes CSS and DOM**. It introduces **scoped styles** to the web
> platform. Without tools or naming conventions, you can **bundle CSS with
> markup**, hide implementation details,
> and author **self-contained components** in vanilla JavaScript.

### Read all about styling components:

- https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom#styling
- (not a standard yet) https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/constructable-stylesheets